# test tooltip on mouse over with selenium driver

Tags: java, testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver

im new using Selenium for testing and i have the next problem. I want to test the tooltips from a pie diagram.

I have the next code:

```
<g class="p0_tooltips">
<g id="p0_tooltip0" class="p0_tooltip" style="opacity: 0;" transform="translate(1960,1500)">
<rect rx="2" ry="2" x="-4" opacity="0.5" style="fill: rgb(0, 0, 0);" width="778" height="27" y="-20">
<text fill="#efefef" style="font-family: arial;">Tooltip</text>
```

When i am with mouse over the option, it shows the value from "text" as tooltip. What i want to prove, is that de value from "opacity" and "transform" changes once i navigate with the mouse but i dont get to do that. I want to prove that for then, testing the content of the tooltip isnt empty.

I have the next code:

```
tooltip = svg.findElement(By.cssSelector(".p0_tooltips"));
tooltips = tooltip.findElements(By.cssSelector(".p0_tooltip"));
for(int i=0; i<tooltips.size(); i++){           
    hover = new Actions(driver);
    tooltipTransform = tooltips.get(i).getAttribute("style");
    System.out.println("OPACITY BEFORE: "+tooltipTransform);
    coordinates = tooltips.get(i).getLocation();
    hover.moveToElement(tooltips.get(i), coordinates.getX() - 10, coordinates.getY() + 10);
    hover.build();

    hover.perform();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    System.out.println("OPACITY AFTER: "+tooltipTransform);
}
```

Someone can help me please?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After performing a hover action you need to call `getAttribute()` again:

```
hover.perform();
Thread.sleep(2000);

tooltipTransform = tooltips.get(i).getAttribute("style");
System.out.println("OPACITY AFTER: " + tooltipTransform);
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for the detail!! The true solutions sometimes are simple!

Comment: what i dont understand, the value from opacity doesnt change but must be change to 1 in the second instance. How can i do a real simulation of tooltip?

Comment: @JaimeMenendezLlana what do you mean by "real simulation of tooltip"?

Comment: Making a click or mouse over in the svg. But the browser didnt do absolutely nothing.